# How to remove gradient effect for UIButton after setting once - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, gradient, quartz-core

I am using UIButton as soft key items. So when i click i would like to show color effects for button. I used the below code to do it.

```
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds;
    btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:.6f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:200.0f/255.0f alpha:.4f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f blue:150.0f/255.0f alpha:.4f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0f/255.0f green:100.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:.4f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:.4f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0f/255.0f green:5.0f/255.0f blue:5.0f/255.0f alpha:.4f] CGColor],

                          nil];
    [btn.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];

    CAGradientLayer *glossLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    glossLayer.frame = btn.bounds;
    glossLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.4f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor,
                         nil];
    glossLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                            nil];
    [btn.layer insertSublayer:glossLayer atIndex:0];

    CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer];
    [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    UIColor*mycolor = btn.backgroundColor;
    [btn.layer setBorderColor:[mycolor CGColor]];
```

Trying to remove the gradient effects for button in below way. Making alpha to zero.. But it didnt work..

```
-(void) removeGradient:(UIButton *)btn{

    CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds;
    btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:200.0f/255.0f blue:200.0f/255.0f alpha:.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f blue:150.0f/255.0f alpha:.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0f/255.0f green:100.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0f/255.0f green:50.0f/255.0f blue:50.0f/255.0f alpha:.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:5.0f/255.0f green:5.0f/255.0f blue:5.0f/255.0f alpha:.0f] CGColor],


                          nil];
    [btn.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];

    CAGradientLayer *glossLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    glossLayer.frame = btn.bounds;
    glossLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.0f].CGColor,
                         nil];
    glossLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                            nil];
    //[btn.layer insertSublayer:glossLayer atIndex:0];

    CALayer *btnLayer = [btn layer];
    [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

}
```

Here, if i click once it is working fine. But if i click on the button repeatedly, then the color is reapplied to the button and after around 10 clicks button completely turns in white color.

I think we have to remove prior gradient effect for layer if we have to redo the effect.
How to remove this gradient effect on layer after setting once.

Thanks
Jithen

Comment: make two button with one button hidden, then copy hidden button to your button ;)

Comment: Rajneesh071 that is not a solution. The proper way is to subclass and respond to touch events. In the touch events the gradient can be modified very easily. This is a very common reason for subclassing UIButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is very common and can be achieved easily through subclassing UIButton. After you have created the subclass add the UIResponder touchEvents to the subclass. In the UIButton subclass, setup an ivar to the gradient and in the touches began and touches ended, change the the properties of the gradient. So on touch began you can invert it and on touches ended you can set it back to the original gradient.

1. Subclass UIButton
2. Create ivar for CAGradient
3. Setup gradient in the initWithFrame method of the UIButton subclass
4. Add UIResponder touch even methods
5. In touchesBegan - modify gradient as you desire.
6. Repeat step 5 in touchesEnded

Again I suggest subclassing because you need to capture the touch events for the button. You cannot do this in the main view controller you have setup the button in.

Let me know if this helps.

**EDIT #1 - Take a look at this example below:**

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.25f].CGColor,
                                                (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.25f].CGColor,
                                                nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75f],
                                                    nil];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.25f].CGColor,
                                                (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.25f].CGColor,
                                                nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75f],
                                                    nil];
}
```

If you notice I am modifying an existing gradient. I am not creating a new one each time. The values that I have will not work for you but it is the concept of not creating a new gradient with each tap. I am modifying the gradient property only.

**EDIT #2 - To create an ivar for your gradients:**

1. Go the the UIButton Subclass Header
2. Add this under the interface section:

   CAGradientLayer *btnGradient;

   CAGradientLayer *glossLayer;

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the same.. but i dont know how to take the button to its original color in touches ended... i mean how to invert the gradient color?

Comment: Just simply change the alpha values of the gradient colors to 0. That will remove the gradient. Also I'm not sure if you have it setup correctly. You said in your above post that the gradient is being reapplied over and over again. Like I said, you should initialize it with the colors that you want and then in the touch events, modify the gradient as you wish.

Comment: I have pasted my code in touches end in my post... Edited my post.. Even after making alpha to 0, my button is not coming to its original color... its turning white after many clicks..

Comment: Okay, I see the code. But what you are doing is adding a gradient on every tap. I stated that you should create an ivar for both gradients that you are making. From there you can modify the gradient in the touch events. The way you have it setup you are adding a new gradient each time.

Comment: Oh.. i am new bee in this.. can u guide me how to create ivar ? Or any article?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Dana.. So u mean i am doing insertSublayer even in remove part which i should not do.. right?

Comment: You mentioned "Setup gradient in the initWithFrame method of the UIButton subclass". This method will be called only when the button is created and initialized.. But i dont want to recreate a button.. i would like to use the existing one. So my button will go to this initwithframe method only once. How to set the "Gradient removal" to  a button in this situation.

Comment: Exactly, you are right. The gradient gets setup in the initializer method. Then in the touchBegan you modify the gradient colors. And then in the touchesEnded you modify the gradient to the original colors. Does that make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29965/discussion-between-jithen-and-dana0550)